# Why does "flex-wrap: wrap" in my css cause the text cells to make a single column?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm working through the [Mozilla website's tutorial on CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), but I can't get the `flex-wrap: wrap` option to work as the tutorial describes. Instead of wrapping the row of text cells around the page, it causes them to expand into a single wide column. The tutorial only gives a screenshot of the result, so I can't check their actual code. I'd be grateful if anyone could tell me what I'm getting wrong.

Here's the full code:

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: purple;
  height: 100px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

article {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: aqua;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* Lines I added following the tutorial */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 200px;
}

article {}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Sample flexbox example</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <article>
    <h2>First article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Second article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Third article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>

    <p>Cray food truck brunch, XOXO +1 keffiyeh pickled chambray waistcoat ennui. Organic small batch paleo 8-bit. Intelligentsia umami wayfarers pickled, asymmetrical kombucha letterpress kitsch leggings cold-pressed squid chartreuse put a bird on it. Listicle
      pickled man bun cornhole heirloom art party.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Fourth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Fifth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Sixth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>

    <p>Cray food truck brunch, XOXO +1 keffiyeh pickled chambray waistcoat ennui. Organic small batch paleo 8-bit. Intelligentsia umami wayfarers pickled, asymmetrical kombucha letterpress kitsch leggings cold-pressed squid chartreuse put a bird on it. Listicle
      pickled man bun cornhole heirloom art party.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Seventh article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Eighth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Ninth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>

    <p>Cray food truck brunch, XOXO +1 keffiyeh pickled chambray waistcoat ennui. Organic small batch paleo 8-bit. Intelligentsia umami wayfarers pickled, asymmetrical kombucha letterpress kitsch leggings cold-pressed squid chartreuse put a bird on it. Listicle
      pickled man bun cornhole heirloom art party.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Tenth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Eleventh article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Twelfth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed.
      PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>

    <p>Cray food truck brunch, XOXO +1 keffiyeh pickled chambray waistcoat ennui. Organic small batch paleo 8-bit. Intelligentsia umami wayfarers pickled, asymmetrical kombucha letterpress kitsch leggings cold-pressed squid chartreuse put a bird on it. Listicle
      pickled man bun cornhole heirloom art party.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Here's the expected tutorial results and what I actually get:

[image: Images of the expected and actual webpages]

The code gives the same result in Chrome, Edge and the CodePen online editor. The W3C html and css validators don't give any errors.

Comment: The `flex: 200px` goes on the flex items, not the flex container.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem: I'd put the "flex: 200px" rule with the section instead of the article. The tutorial had it right, I'd overlooked that instruction.

Answer (score 1):

add width to the article tag.

```
article {
   .
   .
   .
   .
   width: 200px;
}
```

`<article>` tags are block-level elements, so if we don't assign any width separately, they will take the whole page width and the next article element will start from the next row which is why the issue is coming as shown in the screenshots above in question. Providing separate width to the article tag will allow the next article element to come beside the first article element, You can also understand this using the box model.

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it a good answer.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta <article> tags are block-level elements, so if we don't assign any width separately, they will take the whole page width and the next article element will start from the next row which is why the issue is coming as shown in the screenshots above in question. Providing separate width to the article tag will allow the next article element to come beside the first article element, You can also understand this using the box model.

Comment: The explanation was not for me, it was to make your answer into a good answer.  I have copied the comment for you this time.